# Advanced custom fields filtering with taxonomies

Tags: wordpress

I'm working with AdvancedCustomFields and Taxonomies, and I don't find, in the documentation, something that allows me to filter the Taxonomies by the values stored on the `wp_options` table.

I found that [here](http://old.support.advancedcustomfields.com/discussion/5322/get_terms-by-meta/p1).

And, it could by something like [this](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/tutorials/querying-relationship-fields/), but with Taxonomies:

I have a taxonomy called "Person", and I have many fields. For example, I would like to filter by sex and country.

Is there any function that allows me to do this? Or should I work with WP-Query?

Thanks in advance

Comment: To be honest I'd just use wp_query since it has great control over filtering in my experience.

Comment: Yes i agree with @Joe, you get it by using wp_query

Comment: Hi!
I ask in the ACF forum and this is not solved with any function. So I've to work with WP-Query.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have registered the taxonomy with your post you may try with tax_query Query inside the your query_post

```
query_posts( array(  
    'post_type' => 'your post type', 
    'paged' => $paged, 
    'posts_per_page' => 10, 
    'tax_query' => array( 
        array( 
            'taxonomy' => 'person', //or tag or custom taxonomy
            'field' => 'id' 

        ) 
    ) 
) );
```

Comment: How is this an answer? The OP asks for help constructing a query that queries a custom taxonomy's custom fields. This does not provide that. It simply rehashes the example in the [WP Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters). The tax_query => field key does not cover custom fields -- it only takes 'id' or 'slug' for a value.

Comment: can you please check this question http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/188315/order-by-sort-taxonmy-fields-using-taxonmy-custom-field-value